# SpringBoot 1.5.1: health endpoint does not show registered health indicators

Tags: spring-boot, health-monitoring, spring-boot-actuator, spring-rabbit

I upgraded spring boot version from 1.4.2 to 1.5.1. My application depends on RabbitMQ.

While using version 1.4.2 the output of health endpoint was

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 249779191808,
    "free": 160644202496,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "rabbit": {
     "status": "UP",
     "version": "3.6.5"
  }
}
```

After the upgrade, with version 1.5.1 the output is

```
{
  "status": "UP"
}
```

So, diskSpace and rabbit indicators are not there anymore. Strangely in the logs, I can find this:

```
Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$DiskSpaceHealthIndicatorConfiguration.diskSpaceHealthIndicatorProperties()
Registering bean definition for @Bean method org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$RabbitHealthIndicatorConfiguration.rabbitHealthIndicator()
```

and even when I request /health endpoint I can see in the logs that call to RabbitMq is made

```
o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate - Executing callback on RabbitMQ Channel: Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://guest@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@5292883 Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@1aa1a795 [delegate=amqp://guest@0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:5672/, localPort= 59527]
```

Expectedly, if I shut down the RabbitMQ instance the response is

```
{
  "status": "DOWN"
}
```

In my `application.yml` I don't have any configuration for health, so the default configuration is used.

How to get back the old output for health endpoint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to be authenticated to see all the details. 
If you want the content to be available unauthenticated you can add this to your properties

```
management.security.enabled=false
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
```

More details [Spring boot Production Ready Monitoring](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html)

Comment: Works like before after adding `management.security.enabled=false`. Didn't notice that in release notes. Thanks